# auth.getAccessToken() is not a function - Azure AD PowerBI + NodeJS integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerbi

Still am able to get the accessToken successfully but don't understand why I'm getting `auth.getAccessToken` is not a function

### index.js

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/getSingRpt",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (embedData) {
        let reportLoadConfig = {
            type: "report",
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
            accessToken: embedData.accessToken,
            embedUrl: embedData.embedUrl[0].embedUrl
        };
        tokenExpiry = embedData.expiry;
        let report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, reportLoadConfig);
        report.off("loaded");
        report.on("loaded", function () {
            console.log("Report load successful");
        });
        report.off("rendered");
        report.on("rendered", function () {
            console.log("Report render successful");
        });
        report.off("error");
        report.on("error", function (event) {
            let errorMsg = event.detail;
            console.error(errorMsg);
            return;
        });
    },

    error: function (err) {
        let errorContainer = $(".error-container");
        $(".embed-container").hide();
        errorContainer.show();
        let errMsg = JSON.parse(err.responseText)['error'];
        let errorLines = errMsg.split("\r\n");
        let errHeader = document.createElement("p");
        let strong = document.createElement("strong");
        let node = document.createTextNode("Error Details:");
        let errContainer = errorContainer.get(0);
        strong.appendChild(node);
        errHeader.appendChild(strong);
        errContainer.appendChild(errHeader);
        errorLines.forEach(element => {
            let errorContent = document.createElement("p");
            let node = document.createTextNode(element);
            errorContent.appendChild(node);
            errContainer.appendChild(errorContent);
        });
    }
});
```

### Server.js

```
app.get('/getSingRpt', async  (req, res) => {
    try {
       await embedToken.getEmbedParamsForSingleReport().then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
                res.status(200).send({ success: true, data: result });
            })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(400).send({ success: false, message: 'problem in getting report' });
    }
});
```

### embedSConfigService.js

```
async function getEmbedParamsForSingleReport(workspaceId, reportId, additionalDatasetId) {
    const reportInGroupApi = `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${workspaceId}/reports/${reportId}`;
    const headers = await getRequestHeader();
    const result = await fetch(reportInGroupApi, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
    })
    console.log('result', result);

    if (!result.ok) {
        throw result;
    }
    const resultJson = await result.json();
    const reportDetails = new PowerBiReportDetails(resultJson.id, resultJson.name, resultJson.embedUrl);
    const reportEmbedConfig = new EmbedConfig();

    reportEmbedConfig.reportsDetail = [reportDetails];

    let datasetIds = [resultJson.datasetId];
    if (additionalDatasetId) {
        datasetIds.push(additionalDatasetId);
    }

    reportEmbedConfig.embedToken = await getEmbedTokenForSingleReportSingleWorkspace(reportId, datasetIds, workspaceId);
    return reportEmbedConfig;
}


async function getRequestHeader() {
    let tokenResponse;
    let errorResponse;
    try {
        tokenResponse = await auth.getAccessToken();
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.hasOwnProperty('error_description') && err.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
            errorResponse = err.error_description;
        } else {
            errorResponse = err.toString();
        }
        return {
            'status': 401,
            'error': errorResponse
        };
    }

    const token = tokenResponse;
    console.log('TOKEN==>', tokenResponse)
    return {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': utils.getAuthHeader(token)
    };
}
```

### Auth.js

```
const adal = require('adal-node');
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json');
const getAccessToken = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const authMode = config.authenticationMode.toLowerCase();
      const AuthenticationContext = adal.AuthenticationContext;
      let authorityUrl = config.authorityUri;
      if (authMode === 'masteruser') {
        new AuthenticationContext(
          authorityUrl,
        ).acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword(
          config.scope,
          config.pbiUsername,
          config.pbiPassword,
          config.clientId,
          (err, token) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(token);
          },
        );
      } else if (authMode === 'serviceprincipal') {
        authorityUrl = authorityUrl.replace('common', config.tenantId);
        new AuthenticationContext(
          authorityUrl,
        ).acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
          config.scope,
          config.clientId,
          config.clientSecret,
          (err, token) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(token);
          },
        );
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Unknown auth mode'));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      reject(err);
    }
  });
};

getAccessToken()
    .then((token) => console.log(token))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

**updated**

**utilities.js**

```
let config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json");

function getAuthHeader(accessToken) {

    // Function to append Bearer against the Access Token
    return "Bearer ".concat(accessToken);
}
```

[image]

Comment: how is `auth` declared in `embedSConfigService.js` - if it's through an `import` or `require`, then of course it's not defined, since it isn't exported in `Auth.js`

Comment: @JaromandaX actually auth is imported like `const auth = require(__dirname + "/authentication.js");` in `embedSConfigService.js`.. i've not mentioned here

Comment: so, I've given you the reason `auth.getAccessToken();` is not a function, because it isn't - you haven't exported anything from `Auth.js`, certainly not `getAccessToken`

Comment: @JaromandaX my mistake only.. ok after i  properly export and import it issue resolved.. but I'm getting `Authurization [object object]` ..  i updated my thread

Comment: simple: somewhere you're passing an object to something that expects a string - and you haven't shown the code that creates that `Authorization` header anyway - so the problem is in code you have not shown

Comment: I@JaromandaX I've posted everything i've  here.. Sorry Im not fully nodejs dev. could you pls tell me what exactly i should post here? btwn [this is what im trying from OFFICIAL MS EXAMPLE](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/NodeJS/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData)

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed a bit of code because of your misspelling of authorization in the comment .... `utils.getAuthHeader(token)` that's returning an OBJECT rather than a STRING - and you haven't shown what that is

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad. I've updated it now.. pls check

Comment: ok, so instead of `console.log('TOKEN==>', tokenResponse)` ... what is `console.log('TOKEN==>', typeof tokenResponse)` - I bet it's Object, not String

Comment: @JaromandaX the type is objec `TOKEN************* object`

Comment: there you go ... when you coerce an object to string, it becomes, literally `[object object]` - but you need a string in a request header - and since I have no clue what `token`/`tokenResponse` is, I can't be of any further assistance

Comment: @JaromandaX so you mean to say its suppose to be string, right?

Comment: yes, a request header is a string

Comment: can you try `token = tokenResponse.AccessToken` - I believe that will be a string

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX I changed as you said.  that issue fixed but it created new  issue show `http://localhost:5300/getSingRpt 400 (Bad Request)` should i change anything in my server.js or index.js

Comment: No idea - it's your code that is setting the 400 response, and you console.log the error before you do so - perhaps the contents of the error will shed some light into what went wrong

Comment: by the way, using `.then` in an `async` function usually means you're *doing it wrong* - while the code may work fine, I believe there are cases where errors can go uncaught - not 100% sure about that though ... anyway ... `const result = await embedToken.getEmbedParamsForSingleReport();` and use result on the next line is how I'd do it